# Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__(…).context is not a function

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

When I am trying to import dynamically vue components using this code:

```js
const components = require.context('./', true, '/^index\.js$/');
```

I am getting this error:

```js
app.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function
    at Module../asset/app.js (app.js:9)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.0 (app.293d5fe1d8a073fed37a.bundle.js:1747)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at bootstrap:858
    at bootstrap:858
```

Why is that? How to fix that? What have I missed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try changing the third argument from a string to a regex, ie:

```
const components = require.context('./', true, /^index.js$/)
```

I have usages with regexes which work, and others which I'm trying to sort out, which don't use an inline regex like this one.

Side-note: you're asking to find everything from './' downward (recursive: you're setting that flag to `true`), but will only accept one file: `index.js` in the base folder. If that's all you want, I'd suggest changing the recursive flag to false -- it will be quicker.

Comment: Interestingly the arguments need to be literals.

Comment: I already have a regex literal and it's not working. Updated from Angular 14 to 15.

Answer (score 26):

#### Angular 15

I ended up here after getting a similar issue in my app after upgrading from Angular 14 to Angular 15. I solved it [this way](https://github.com/azerothcore/Keira3/pull/2054/commits/13c11ad1ab1457d8e0189d4eeb34507a412e1f08) by editing the `angular.json` file and in the project `"test"` changing its `"options"` by removing `"main": "src/test.ts",` and adding this instead:

```
"polyfills": ["zone.js", "zone.js/testing"],
```

then the `src/test.ts` file can be removed

Comment: I had the same problem after updating NG 14 → 15. For me, https://stackoverflow.com/a/74572172/256646 (deleting 2 lines in `src/test.ts`) solved the problem.

Comment: But that only explains it for tests. I have this problem in non-test code and my regex is a literal. It worked in Angular 14, now it breaks with 15.

Answer (score 9):

**Angular 15**

I'm got the same error after updating Angular from 14 to 15. But I'm using require.context inside my app logic - so removing the test files wasn't enough for me.

Instead, I replaced require.context() with [import.meta.webpackContext()](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-variables/#importmetawebpackcontext).

*Before:*

```
(require as any).context(
    'frontmatter-markdown-loader!./blog-content/',
    true,
    /^\.\/.+\.md$/
)
```

*After:*

```
(import.meta as any).webpackContext(
    'frontmatter-markdown-loader!./blog-content/', 
    { recursive: true, regExp: /^\.\/.+\.md$/ }
)
```

Comment: This was the solution for me too! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can I ask you for what are you using import.meta.webpackContext() in your application?

Answer (score 3):

[doc link](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext)

there is a sentence `The arguments passed to require.context must be literals` in docs.
The third argument should be a literals like `/^index.js$/`. I got the same error when I used `new RegExp()`