# Getting error while trying to grab list of source code files: TypeError: webpack_require(...).context is not a function

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm having a documentation application where examples of components come next to source code (ts, html, scss sources can be seen along with working components). While migrating from angular 13 to angular 15 I've met with the following problem

I'm having a token in AppModule providers list

```
{
    provide: DEMO_PATH_TOKEN_SCSS,
    useFactory: () => (require as any).context(`!sass-loader!./`, true, /.*\.(scss)$/),
}
```

This function is used to grab list of source files (after that this list if filtered by each container component that holds and example), this particular case is for scss sources, there're similar for ts and html. The token is injected in service (that is not provided in root)

```
@Injectable()
export class SourcesService {
    constructor(
        @SkipSelf() @Optional() @Inject(DEMO_PATH_TOKEN_SCSS) private contextScss: any
    ) { }
}
```

When I open a page with a component that provides `SourcesService` I'm getting the following error

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: **webpack_require**(...).context is not a function
> TypeError: **webpack_require**(...).context is not a function

How can I fix that?

Comment: Thise could be a regex issue like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56644864/uncaught-typeerror-webpack-require-context-is-not-a-function).

Comment: Thank you @dmitryro, that does not look like a regexp issue, still third answer there seem to be the case, still there're another problems with replacing require.context() with import.meta.webpackContext(), I've updated the question

Answer (score 1):

This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/75264128/574686) to similar question is the case!

One need to change require.context() with import.meta.webpackContext().

```
{
    provide: DEMO_PATH_TOKEN_SCSS,
    useFactory: () => (require as any).context(`!sass-loader!./`, true, /.*\.(scss)$/),
}
```

Should be replaced with

```
{
    provide: DEMO_PATH_TOKEN_SCSS,
    useFactory: () => (import.meta as any).webpackContext(
        `!!raw-loader!./`,
        { recursive: true, regExp: /.*\.(scss)$/ }
    ),
},
```